# why does BeautifulSoup match some class names but not others

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am struggling to understand why BeautifulSoup is not matching some class names that exist in the HTML source.

The original HTML code contains the following lines to be matched:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="34">1,148.52</span>

<div class="Py(16px)">...

<div class="Mt(15px)" data-reactid="4">...
```

The following is my code:

```
# ref: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class 

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# the folowing matches ok
print(soup.find('div', class_="Mt(15px)"))

# yet, the following lines fail to match:
print(soup.find("span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"))
print(soup.find('span', {"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"}))
print(soup.find('div', class_="Py(16px)"))
```

I thought maybe the class names are not working with BeautifulSoup, so I tried using page.content.replace("old class name", "new") to shorten and simplify the class names for the BeautifulSoup function, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried printing the HTML content out and seeing if the elements you want are there?  I suspect that the elements you want  are dynamically loaded with JavaScript; therefore, not available when you grab it via `requests`. There is nothing wrong with your class definition in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: What value is Py(16px) supposed to return?

Comment: QHarr: it's just a random class I copied from the HTML to test.  facelessuser: I think you're right; I tried writing page.text to a file and couldn't find the missing class names there, while the working class name did exist.  Is there a standard way to deal with this JavaScript issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely robust but you can grab that info from one of the script tabs

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL?p=GOOGL')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
scripts = [script.text for script in soup.select('script') if '/* -- Data -- */' in script.text]
script = scripts[0].split('App.main = ')[1].replace('\n','').replace(';}(this));','')
data = json.loads(script)
content = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['StreamDataStore']['quoteData']['GOOGL']

print(content['longName'])
print(content['regularMarketPrice']['fmt'])
print(content['regularMarketChange']['fmt'])
print(content['regularMarketChangePercent']['fmt'])
```